# Using Geotools from Clojure - Unhandled java.lang.NoSuchFieldError METER

Tags: java, clojure, geotools

Okay, so the guts of the issue is I'm getting this error:

```
 Unhandled java.lang.NoSuchFieldError
 METER
```

Stacktrace:

```
               Parser.java:  560  org.geotools.referencing.wkt.Parser/parseSpheroid
               Parser.java:  656  org.geotools.referencing.wkt.Parser/parseDatum
               Parser.java:  867  org.geotools.referencing.wkt.Parser/parseGeoGCS
               Parser.java:  224  org.geotools.referencing.wkt.Parser/parseCoordinateReferenceSystem
               Parser.java:  204  org.geotools.referencing.wkt.Parser/parseCoordinateReferenceSystem
ReferencingObjectFactory.java: 1090  org.geotools.referencing.factory.ReferencingObjectFactory/createFromWKT
        PrjFileReader.java:   94  org.geotools.data.PrjFileReader/<init>
        PrjFileReader.java:   68  org.geotools.data.PrjFileReader/<init>
  ShapefileSetManager.java:  106  org.geotools.data.shapefile.ShapefileSetManager/openPrjReader
ShapefileFeatureSource.java:  519  org.geotools.data.shapefile.ShapefileFeatureSource/readAttributes
ShapefileFeatureSource.java:  475  org.geotools.data.shapefile.ShapefileFeatureSource/buildFeatureType
ShapefileFeatureStore.java:  132  org.geotools.data.shapefile.ShapefileFeatureStore/buildFeatureType
 ContentFeatureSource.java:  343  org.geotools.data.store.ContentFeatureSource/getAbsoluteSchema
 ContentFeatureSource.java:  312  org.geotools.data.store.ContentFeatureSource/getSchema
     ContentDataStore.java:  345  org.geotools.data.store.ContentDataStore/getSchema
NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:   -2  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl/invoke0
NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:   62  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl/invoke
DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:   43  sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl/invoke
               Method.java:  483  java.lang.reflect.Method/invoke
            Reflector.java:   93  clojure.lang.Reflector/invokeMatchingMethod
            Reflector.java:   28  clojure.lang.Reflector/invokeInstanceMethod
              geometry.clj:   40  grafter.tabular.geometry/store->dataset
              geometry.clj:   39  grafter.tabular.geometry/store->dataset
              geometry.clj:   51  grafter.tabular.geometry/eval17505/fn
              MultiFn.java:  233  clojure.lang.MultiFn/invoke
                common.clj:  191  grafter.tabular.common/dispatch-with-format-option
                common.clj:  180  grafter.tabular.common/dispatch-with-format-option
                common.clj:  197  grafter.tabular.common/eval1293/fn
              MultiFn.java:  233  clojure.lang.MultiFn/invoke
                common.clj:  200  grafter.tabular.common/read-dataset
                common.clj:  199  grafter.tabular.common/read-dataset
               RestFn.java:  410  clojure.lang.RestFn/invoke
                      REPL:   44  grafter.tabular.geometry/eval17511
                      REPL:   44  grafter.tabular.geometry/eval17511
             Compiler.java: 6927  clojure.lang.Compiler/eval
             Compiler.java: 6890  clojure.lang.Compiler/eval
                  core.clj: 3105  clojure.core/eval
                  core.clj: 3101  clojure.core/eval
                  main.clj:  240  clojure.main/repl/read-eval-print/fn
                  main.clj:  240  clojure.main/repl/read-eval-print
                  main.clj:  258  clojure.main/repl/fn
                  main.clj:  258  clojure.main/repl
                  main.clj:  174  clojure.main/repl
               RestFn.java: 1523  clojure.lang.RestFn/invoke
    interruptible_eval.clj:   87  clojure.tools.nrepl.middleware.interruptible-eval/evaluate/fn
                  AFn.java:  152  clojure.lang.AFn/applyToHelper
                  AFn.java:  144  clojure.lang.AFn/applyTo
                  core.clj:  646  clojure.core/apply
                  core.clj: 1881  clojure.core/with-bindings*
                  core.clj: 1881  clojure.core/with-bindings*
               RestFn.java:  425  clojure.lang.RestFn/invoke
    interruptible_eval.clj:   85  clojure.tools.nrepl.middleware.interruptible-eval/evaluate
    interruptible_eval.clj:   55  clojure.tools.nrepl.middleware.interruptible-eval/evaluate
    interruptible_eval.clj:  222  clojure.tools.nrepl.middleware.interruptible-eval/interruptible-eval/fn/fn
    interruptible_eval.clj:  190  clojure.tools.nrepl.middleware.interruptible-eval/run-next/fn
                  AFn.java:   22  clojure.lang.AFn/run
   ThreadPoolExecutor.java: 1142  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor/runWorker
   ThreadPoolExecutor.java:  617  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker/run
               Thread.java:  745  java.lang.Thread/run
```

When calling a function that uses some geotools functionality from `org.geotools/gt-shapefile`. My starting version was `15.1`.

The weird thing is that we're using this project (version `13.2`) in a virtually identical app, using the same calling code and same namespace to call from; yet using that version doesn't work here - the same error is thrown.

I've tried:

- multiple versions of the lib in question, starting with `15.1` and rolling back from there
- multiple versions of clojure
- multiple versions of our internal libs that differ between the two projects

I've seen from looking around that this seems to be a dependency issue, but I'm not sure exactly where it occurs.

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: Calling code is the same, so didn't seem relevant. It's a fresh lein app from a template, so the only differences are in deps.

Answer (score 5):

After quite a while, I managed to work this out - and wanted to make sure it was on SO for posterity. The problem is in the `javax.measure` library; you can see the fields [here](http://jscience.org/api/javax/measure/unit/SI.html). There are [two](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.java.dev.jsr-275/jsr-275) [versions](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.measure/jsr-275) on maven and continued development post-May 2010 is [elsewhere](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.measure/unit-api).

A lot of projects mix this in, and dependency mismatch can happen pretty easily. In our case, Apache Tika was the culprit. One of our internal libs uses Tika, and that uses:

```
[javax.measure/jsr-275 "0.9.3"]
```

Whereas Geotools uses:

```
[net.java.dev.jsr-275/jsr-275 "1.0-beta-2”]
```

Thus, adding the following to any projects in your `project.clj` that refer to `javax.measure` will solve the issue:

```
 [library "x.x.x" :exclusions [javax.measure/jsr-275]]
```

To identify these, use `$ lein deps :tree` to explore your dependencies.